# swift2 How to parse variable spaced text

Tags: swift2

I have the following data (a portion shown below) and I'm trying to determine the best way to parse this into an array where each line would be parsed separately. The problem I'm running into is that each "column" is separated by a various number of spaces.

I have tried using .componentsSeparatedBySpaces("  ") but that doesn't give me a consistent number items in the array. I thought of using whiteSpace but some team names have 2 words in them and some have 3.

A sample of the text follows:

```
   1  New England Patriots    =  28.69    5   0   0   20.34(  13)   1  0  0 |   3  0  0 |   28.68    1 |   28.95    1 |   28.66    2
   2  Green Bay Packers       =  27.97    6   0   0   17.80(  28)   1  0  0 |   1  0  0 |   27.47    2 |   28.73    2 |   29.01    1
   3  Denver Broncos          =  26.02    6   0   0   19.02(  23)   0  0  0 |   2  0  0 |   25.21    5 |   27.25    3 |   27.98    3
   4  Cincinnati Bengals      =  25.96    6   0   0   19.91(  18)   1  0  0 |   3  0  0 |   25.71    4 |   26.38    4 |   26.36    4
   5  Arizona Cardinals       =  25.01    4   2   0   18.05(  27)   0  1  0 |   0  1  0 |   26.47    3 |   24.17    6 |   23.37    7
   6  Pittsburgh Steelers     =  24.87    4   2   0   21.17(  10)   1  1  0 |   1  2  0 |   25.17    6 |   24.53    5 |   24.39    5
   7  Seattle Seahawks        =  24.04    2   4   0   20.92(  12)   0  2  0 |   0  3  0 |   24.47    7 |   23.29    7 |   23.37    6
   8  Philadelphia Eagles     =  23.87    3   3   0   20.02(  17)   1  1  0 |   2  2  0 |   24.28    8 |   23.01    8 |   23.23    8
   9  New York Jets           =  22.95    4   1   0   18.41(  25)   0  1  0 |   0  1  0 |   23.83    9 |   22.77   10 |   21.69   11
  10  Atlanta Falcons         =  22.18    5   1   0   19.31(  21)   1  0  0 |   3  0  0 |   22.36   10 |   22.33   11 |   21.86   10
```

Comment: You'll need to read each line into a string variable and use `substringWithRange` to get each "column".

Comment: The number of spaces does not matter if each data item is on a unique position to begin with. If anything, it is easier – "Green Bay Packers" has more spaces than "Atlanta Falcons" and so your own attempt is doomed to fail on that alone.

Comment: You could use NSRegularExpression and capture groups to break up each line.